Apple Mail keeps downloading messages
I am using a MacBook Air M1 (2020) with Sequoia 15.0 (24A335) and Mail Version 16.0 (3818.100.11.1.3). I use the Apple Mail application with accounts from iCloud, Outlook, and Google.
For the past 10 days, the Mail app has not been working properly:

It keeps downloading messages, especially from Gmail. From time to time, when opening the "Flagged" folder, most of the flagged emails from those accounts simply disappear. After closing and opening the app a few times, it starts downloading them again (thousands of emails).
Even when the messages do not disappear, downloading/receiving new emails takes a considerable amount of time, especially (perhaps only) from the Gmail accounts.

I tried to rebuild the mailboxes several times, and also removing and adding the accounts, but nothing fixes the problem.
